# I'm having administrative privilege error with wsus offline

Tags: windows-7, windows, wsus

I'm having administrative privilege problem with wsus offline
It always give me this error whenever I ran the update it is my first time using this but my account is already is an administrator it always give me this error

[Here is my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZD2xC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

According to the thread below, you need to run DoUpdate.bat in an elevated command prompt in order for WSUS Offline to run correctly (this has been the case since the introduction of UAC in Windows Vista).

https://forums.wsusoffline.net/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=3743#p11279